# javascript how to find from two object array ?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have two array object

```
 var data=[{m:1},{m:2},{m:3},{m:4},{m:5},{m:6},{m:7},{m:8},{m:9},{m:10},{m:11},{m:12}];
 var file=[{m:1},{m:3}];
```

i want to get array like `[true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]`

Note : in this ayyar it will return true if it match with file array object from data array object.

i try [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) but i cann't work for my result.

Comment: Your expected result is wrong, it should be: `[true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
 let data = [{m:1},{m:2},{m:3},{m:4},{m:5},{m:6},{m:7},{m:8},{m:9},{m:10},{m:11},{m:12}];
 let file = [{m:1},{m:3}];
 
 let result = data.map(d => file.some(f => f.m === d.m));
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a hash table and map the occurence.

```js
var data = [{ m: 1 }, { m: 2 }, { m: 3 }, { m: 4 }, { m: 5 }, { m: 6 }, { m: 7 }, { m: 8 }, { m: 9 }, { m: 10 }, { m: 11 }, { m: 12 }],
    file = [{ m: 1 }, { m: 3 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;
    
file.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.m] = true;
});

result = data.map(function (a) {
    return hash[a.m] || false;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var data = [{ m: 1 }, { m: 2 }, { m: 3 }, { m: 4 }, { m: 5 }, { m: 6 }, { m: 7 }, { m: 8 }, { m: 9 }, { m: 10 }, { m: 11 }, { m: 12 }],
    file = [{ m: 1 }, { m: 3 }],
    mySet = new Set(file.map(a => a.m)),
    result = data.map(a => mySet.has(a.m));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The lookup table/set is bound to be faster than my approach, especially as the list grows longer +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/dtsx2g0g/2/)

```js
var data=[{m:1},{m:2},{m:3},{m:4},{m:5},{m:6},{m:7},{m:8},{m:9},{m:10},{m:11},{m:12}];
 var file=[{m:1},{m:3}];
 var re = [];
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  let r = file.find(function findObj(o) { 
    return o.m === data[i].m;
 })
if(r){
   re.push(true)
  }else{
  re.push(false)
  }
 }
 console.log(re)
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but there is only one true in your answer which is not matched with expected output of OP.

Answer (score 0):

Funny how ridiculously small it becomes with ES6.

Here, `file.map(val => val.m)` would give me an array of numbers. `[1, 3]` which I use to find whether it includes current object's `m` prop.

```js
 var data=[{m:1},{m:2},{m:3},{m:4},{m:5},{m:6},{m:7},{m:8},{m:9},{m:10},{m:11},{m:12}];
 var file=[{m:1},{m:3}];
 var selection = file.map(val => val.m)
 
 var arr = data.map(obj => selection.includes(obj.m))
 
 console.log(arr)
```

Comment: for each iteration of data, you generate a new array for look up.

Comment: @NinaScholz maybe I should create it first and then use it inside?

Comment: or a set, like in my answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz okay, got it, +1, but how would one learn/know which one would be faster approach? how do you go for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{m:1},{m:2},{m:3},{m:4},{m:5},{m:6},{m:7},{m:8},{m:9},{m:10},{m:11},{m:12}];
var file = [{m:1},{m:3}];

var result = [];

function remove_duplicates(data, file) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0, len2 = file.length; j < len2; j++) { 
            if (data[i].m === file[j].m) {
                result.push("true")
            }else{
            result.push("false")
            }
        }
    }
console.log(result)
}

remove_duplicates(data,file);
```